# Android Emulator Toggle Cell Networking on MacOSX

Tags: android, macos, emulation, shortcut

I'm trying to toggle cell network on Android Emulator running on MacOSX. It works great on Windows with F8 (as documented), but it seems not to be the same shortcut on Mac. Does anyone know how to toggle cell network on MacOSX?

Answer (score 2):

If you are on a Mac laptop try using <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd>. I think some of the function keys on these macs trigger special actions by default. By holding <kbd>Fn</kbd> you get the plain function key instead.

[This can be changed in the keyboard settings](http://knowledgeexplosion.info/2010/06/solved-working-eclipse-short-cuts-function-keys-in-mac-os-x-snow-leopard/)

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse , Go to :: `Menu  >>  Window  >>  Show View  >>  Others  >>  Android  >>  Emulator Control`

then you will see the options like:

[image]

Here if you select unregisterd in Data: option then it will toggle your emulator network.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out F8 and Fn + F8 won't work because other system applications are already listening on these keys. You need to go to "System Preferences" -> "Keyboard" and remove the checks for F8 key or remove the key alltogether (probably Expose is listening to it).